# Crear Clase para chat con php

Tags: php, class

Como dice el título, quería saber como se puede crear una Clase para un chat en PHP que tenga la siguiente estructura.

```
$mensaje->send
$mensaje->delete
```

Pero no sé como, porque hay que crear el constructor de la clase de la siguiente manera

`$mensaje = new Message()`

la función **delete** utiliza una variable de un ID y la función de **send** necesita una variable de un texto y cuando pongo una sóla variable que es la que necesita dicha función, el constructor me da error porque no encuentra la otra variable de la otra función.

Comment: No se entiende muy bien lo que dices. ¿Puedes poner el código completo donde tienes la dificultad para poder ayudarte?

Comment: La pregunta que formulé es casualmente porque no sé como hacer una clase en php y tengo problemas con el constructor, porque la clase que quiero tiene dos funciones y las dos funciones requieren dos variables distintas, pero si pongo sólo una variable, el constructor me da error, porque falta la variable de la otra función. Entonces lo que quería saber es como crear una Clase que cumpla estas características.

Comment: En ese caso debes revisar la documentación sobre las clases. Allí se explica que una cosa es el constructor y otra cosa son los métodos (o funciones) de la clase. Parece que estás confundido, pensando que todo debe ir en el constructor cuando no es así. Por ejemplo, puedes dejar el constructor vacío y luego dotar a tu clase de dos (o más métodos), cada uno de esos métodos recibirá sus propios parámetros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Alternativa #1

Tal como lo planteas, el código quedaría:

```
class Message {

    public function send($msg)
    {
        // Lógica para enviar mensaje.
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        // Lógica para borrar el mensaje con $id.
    }

}

$mensaje = new Message();
$mensaje->send('¡Hola!');
$mensaje->delete(1000);
```

---

### Alternativa #2

Ahora, quizá quieras que el id se genere por cada nuevo mensaje enviado:

```
class Message {

    protected $id:
    protected $msg;

    public __construct($msg) {
        $this->msg = $msg;
    }

    public function send()
    {
        // Lógica para enviar mensaje.
        $this->id = uniqid();
    }

    public function delete()
    {
        $id = $this->id;
        // Lógica para borrar el mensaje con $id.
    }

}

$mensaje = new Message('Texto a enviar.');
$mensaje->send();
$mensaje->delete();
```

Te recomiendo la siguiente lectura para reforzar el tema: [Instancia de clases en PHP](https://diego.com.es/instancia-de-clases-en-php).